# Navigation between html pages on form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on static pages only.. no backend is present...Hi trying to navigate between html pages, and succeesful in that. But need to switch the page only when the form is properly validate, have tried but its not working..
Need some help...

HTML:

```
<div class="formContainer">
        <form class="form" id="loginForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Login</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="loginForm-email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="loginForm-email" name="loginForm-email" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="loginForm-password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginForm-password" name="loginForm-password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
              var fnValidate =  $("#loginForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        "loginForm-email": {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },  
                        "loginForm-password": {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 5
                        } 
                    }
                });

                 $('.btn').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(fnValidate){
                    window.location.reload(true);
                    window.location.href = '../html/userPage.html';
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('hia');
                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: if i was you, i'd first of all avoid using `button type="submit"` if you want your js to take care of submitting the form, and would use `type="button"` instead, otherwise i don't think the `preventDefault` will work...

Comment: ...also, if you want to make use of the form data, instead of redirecting (`window.location...`), you should make use of the native js form `submit()` function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery validator has custom success and failure callbacks which you can use.

As per your current approach, the fnValidate will return you an object. So you won't know whether it's validated or not. So try using the following approach.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loginForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "loginForm-email": {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
                "loginForm-password": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            console.log("inside valid");
            window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = '../html/userPage.html';
            // this.submit()
        },
        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
            // 'this' refers to the form
            console.log("Please fill the form");
        }


    });

});
```

jsfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/2vvaN/2/

submitHandler is called only if the form is valid. So there you can submit the form.

Comment: Is there any way to load the other html file instead of using window.location.href.. 
I tried using .load() but it is not working...

Comment: Make that URL the form's action and just ditch the custom submitHandlers. The validate plugin should only allow the form to submit when it validates and then it will go to your other HTML.

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle sample [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/2vvaN/3/) As @christian314159 told, remove the action handlers and just put action attribute in the form tag.